# Pandas loc() method with boolean array on axis 1

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, boolean, pandas-loc

I am experimenting with the Pandas `loc()` method, used with boolean arrays as arguments.

I created a small dataframe to play with:

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4
 0  a        1       2       3
 1  b       NaN     NaN      6
 2  c       NaN      8       9
 3  d       NaN     11       12
 4  e       13       14      15
 5  f       17      18       19
 6  g       21  2    2       23
```

And a boolean array to use on axis 1 to subset a number of columns:

```
 a1 = pd.Series([True, False, True, False])
```

I then tried:

```
 df.loc[: , a1]
```

I got an error message:

> IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided

How can I apply the boolean array to subset a number of columns with `loc()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need convert `Series` to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
print (df.loc[: , a1.values])
  col1  col3
0    a   2.0
1    b   NaN
2    c   8.0
3    d  11.0
4    e  14.0
5    f  18.0
6    g   2.0
```

Or need add `index` by `df.columns` for alignment `index` of `Series` to `columns` of `DataFrame`:

```
a1 = pd.Series([True, False, True, False], index=df.columns)
print (df.loc[: , a1])
  col1  col3
0    a   2.0
1    b   NaN
2    c   8.0
3    d  11.0
4    e  14.0
5    f  18.0
6    g   2.0
```